# Off-server thumbnailing is not allowed phpthumb cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, phpthumb

I am working on `cakephp` based project

Making thumbnails using `phpThumb` plugin

need to create thumbnail of an external image link

`phpThumb` is generating thumbnail from this server

`http://watermark.propspace.com`

but not from this server

`https://propspaceuae.s3.amazonaws.com`

i am getting this error `Off-server thumbnailing is not allowed`

to solve this i did the following

in `phpThumb.config.php` file

i changed `nohotlink_enabled` false

`$PHPTHUMB_CONFIG['nohotlink_enabled'] = false;`

and added domain on `nohotlink_valid_domains`

`$PHPTHUMB_CONFIG['nohotlink_valid_domains'] = array(@$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],'propspaceuae.s3.amazonaws.com');`

but not worked for me

i found this solution here [Link](https://forums.modx.com/index.php?action=thread&thread=67007&i=1)

but this is not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution by changing this line

`$PHPTHUMB_CONFIG['nohotlink_enabled'] = false;`

to

`$PHPTHUMB_CONFIG['nohotlink_enabled'] = true;`

and i added domain in `phpThumb.class.php` file

`var $config_nohotlink_valid_domains = array('propspaceuae.s3.amazonaws.com');`

And it worked for me.